# D7: How do export content types, module settings, taxonomy terms, webforms and other nodes?

Tags: importing-exporting

It seems D7 lacks an important feature for migrating data content types, module settings, taxonomy terms, webforms and other nodes.

I tried with Features modules but it seems it creates modules out of features and this is bad.

Where is Drupal CCK Content Copy Module  for Drupal 7?

Comment: Features create an exportable in a module because it is much easier than anything in the db. Not sure why you think it is bad?

Comment: It might be bad when you export from a multiple language website default english with content types interconnected with node references to a website that has default other language like in my case...

Answer (score 5):

It is **not** bad.  It is preferable to store as much configuration as possible in code, so that it can be version-controlled and deployed easily elsewhere with [Git](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Git_%28software%29) etc..  [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) makes this possible somewhat, but it is not yet feature-complete.  Some work that is still on-going:

- Taxonomy terms: This will be implemented with a combination of Features and [Deploy](http://drupal.org/project/deploy), but it is not quite ready.  See http://drupal.org/node/1245582#comment-5146834 for details.
- Content type settings: A fair amount of this is now working, but [Strongarm](http://drupal.org/project/strongarm) needs to be set up first for these to be exported with Features.  See [Features does not capture important settings while exporting a content type](http://drupal.org/node/1105670) for details.

As there is no more [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) in Drupal 7, that content-copy feature is no longer available.  We've moved onto Fields.  If you want a quick way to get bundles exported without getting into Features, check out the [Bundle copy](http://drupal.org/project/bundle_copy) module.